# How can I test whether a string only contains characters in a given set?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Given a string of a mobile phone number, I need to make sure that the given string only contains digits `0-9`, `(`,`)`,`+`,`-`,`x`, and space. How can I do it in Ruby?

Comment: Ruby RegEx syntax is borrowed from Perl. As you know regex in Perl, you can use the same here too.

Comment: A potential problem is that phone number formats vary around the world. Unless you know the region and you did _NOT_ let users enter them by hand, the input could generate false warnings. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/128421

Comment: A much more thorough discussion with examples is https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/128421

Comment: Rather than try to reinvent a wheel use an existing wheel: "[telephone_number](https://github.com/mobi/telephone_number)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
/^[-0-9()+x ]+$/
```

E.g.:

```
re = /^[-0-9()+x ]+$/
match = re.match("555-555-5555")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (/^[-\d()\+x ]+$/.match(variable))
  puts "MATCH"
else
  puts "Does not MATCH"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-count):

```
"+1 (800) 123-4567".count("^0-9+x()\\- ").zero?  # => true
"x invalid string x".count("^0-9+x()\\- ").zero? # => false
```